# How to hide or change the server hostname on LAMP stack?

Tags: server

I have a LAMP stack on Contabo, and I just can't change or hide the server hostname.

I have changed /etc/hosts and /etc/hostname without luck.

Thanks

Comment: Apache will return the vhost name if you configure a namebased virtual host.